# Representation of states in $C^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^* $-algebra, let $\pi : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}(H)$ be a representation of $\mathcal{A}$ on the space of bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space $H$ and let $\omega: \mathcal{A} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a state on $\mathcal{A} $. In order to "represent" $\omega $, I think we need $\pi $ to be injective (and thus an isomorphism), so that $\pi (\mathcal{A})$ is itself a $C^*$-algebra and the map

$$\tau : \pi (\mathcal{A}) \to \mathbb{C}$$

defined by $\tau \big( \pi (A) \big) = \omega (A)$, $\forall A \in \mathcal{A}$ is indeed a state. Furthermore, by the Hahn-Banach theorem, we can extend $\tau$ to a state on $\mathcal{B}(H)$.

**Question 1:** is the above construction of $\tau$ on $\mathcal{B}(H)$ correct?

**Question 2:** what are the properties of $\tau$ given $\omega$? For instance, when is $\tau$ normal?

Comment: Is $\pi$ injective? If not, $\pi(A_1)$ and $\pi(A_2)$ can be same element and if $\omega$ takes different values on $A_1$ and $A_2$, then the state will not be well defined.

Comment: @Arindam yes, so $\pi$ needs to be injective

Comment: The construction of the trace is on $\mathcal{A}$, not on $\mathcal{B}(H)$. The construction is correct as long as $\pi$ is faithful(injective). What do you mean by normal trace? Are you asking whether it is normalized at some $a \in \mathcal{A}$, means $\tau (a)=1$?

Comment: @Arindam I didn't mention the trace...

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to ask: What do you mean by $\tau$ is normal?